# webpack configuration using html-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using HTML-Webpack-plugin with build setting:

```
build: {
  env: require('./prod.env'),
  index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/templates/dist/index.html'),
  assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/static'),
  assetsSubDirectory: 'dist'
```

app structure:

```
app-
    static-
        dist-
            css- minified css files
            js- minified js files
    templates-
        dist-
            index.html
```

When the output is built using npm run build the output index.html file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><title>app</title><link href=/dist/css/app.22f236.css
```

However, I want the href path to include /static prior to /dist for all paths in index.html ie

```
/static/dist/css...
```

my webpack.prod.conf.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: {
        safe: true
      }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vender modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

I there any way to change the injected path in index.html to include a parent folder in front of each path? (other than writing a bash script to do this).

Comment: how does your webpack configuration look?

Comment: I've added the entire prod.conf file settings to question above

Comment: try to add `publicPath: '/'` in webpack `output`. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output paths for compilation assets do not depend on settings you can provide with `html-webpack-plugin` (aside for the HTML file itself). You will have to configure the compiler output path and module rules to ensure that the assets get emitted at a desired public path.

Comment: The assets get emitted ok at assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/static') but I'd like webpack to add a directory name prefix to the path in index.html so that the server can find the assets, if possible

Comment: You'll have to reach for the module rules for that. For instance, if you want to change the path at which your CSS asset is referenced and you use `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, you'll have to configure it's `publicPath`option. `html-webpack-plugin` merely uses the asset's public path as it was defined elsewhere when it was added to the compilation. The same holds true for assets added with `file-loader`, etc.